# Eclipse Indigo: Compiler compliance level 1.7 is missing from the list

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Java 7 JDK (jdk-7u9-windows-x64.exe) and started up Eclipse Indigo to try a statement using the new diamond syntax. It does not compile. 
I have added jdk1.7.0_09 in Preferences - Java - Installed JREs. 
Under Preferences - Java - Compiler I wanted to set 1.7 compliance level, but my drop-down list only contains 1.3 - 1.6. How can I get 1.7 to appear here?
Version: Indigo Release Build id: 20110615-0604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from eclipse page:

> Download Eclipse 3.7SR2 for out of the box support. Or, follow the
>   steps below to get the JDT source code in an earlier build and launch
>   a runtime workbench which will contain Java 7 features.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java7

Edit:
Eclipse indigo sr2 can be downloaded: [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2)

Comment: when i tried to follow instructions from http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java7 , got error "could not connect to :extssh:pserver@dev.eclipse.org:/cvsroot/rt

Comment: I think some eclipse stuff has been migrated from cvs to git. http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_FAQ might be the cause of problem

Answer (score 2):

Bad luck for [Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/717567/), install Juno.

Comment: Thanks. Eh... wouldn't a link on Juno have been more useful then?